# how to calculate a rolling average based on a column in spotfire

Tags: properties, average, document, spotfire

I have a data set where you have a Document Property that Selects "items", each "item" has a particular "usage days". I want to calculate an output of "Moving Average" for 1 or more selected items. the data for the moving average lives under a column named "usage days".

How do I calculate this taking into account the "selected date of my choice" and the rolling average number of days of my choice.

Do you have particular ideas of how I can perform the calculation i.e. in a calculated column or a text field?

Car/        Trip    /  Start Date/      End Date    /          Days on trip

1           AB123   /   2       /     6/07/2013

1           AB234   /  29/07/2013   /   6/09/2013   / 42

1           AB345   /6/09/2013  /28/09/2013 /22

1           AB456   /29/09/2013 /21/10/2013 /23

2          AB567    / 26/10/2013    / 12/11/2013    / 22

2          AB678    /12/11/2013 /8/12/2013  /26

[The rows above have an example of the problem (sorry couldn't paste an image because im new), I want to calculate the %usage of the Car and or cars for a selected range of time e.g (Select date range JUlY to AUGUST then (#of days on trip for car 1and 2)/#on days in that period)/2*100]

Comment: Could you provide a data sample / small table? Otherwise it is difficult to see what you expect as a result.

Answer (score 0):

As phiver said, it is still difficult to see what you expect as a result... but I think I have something that might work. First, I slightly altered the dataset you provided, like so:

```
car trip    startDate   endDate daysOnTrip
1   AB123   7/6/2013    7/29/2013   23
1   AB234   7/29/2013   9/6/2013    42
1   AB345   9/6/2013    9/28/2013   22
1   AB456   9/29/2013   10/21/2013  23
2   AB567   10/26/2013  11/12/2013  22
2   AB678   11/12/2013  12/8/2013   26
```

I then added 2 document properties, "DateRangeFirst" and "DateRangeLast", to allow the user to select beginning and ending dates. Next I made input box property controls for each of the aforementioned document properties in a text area so the user can alter the date range. I then added a datatable visualization with a "Limit data using expression:" of "[startDate] >= Date(${DateRangeFirst}) and [endDate]<= Date(${DateRangeLast})" so we could see the trips selected. Finally, to get the average you appear to be looking for, a barchart set to % of total (daysOnTrip) / car with the same data limiting expression as above. The below screenshot should have everything you need to reproduce my results. I hope this gives you what you need.

**NOTE:** With this method if you select a date in the middle of a trip, an entire row and all of the days on that trip will be ignored.

[image]